# To open calendar application and to get click event of date in android

Tags: android

I want to open default calendar application of android device and to get the click event of date.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests you are implementing a method for choosing a date. Surely the DatePicker widget would be more suitable? A tutorial [can be found here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html)

Comment: Hello LBNerdbard,
Thanks for reply, but I do not want to use date picker widget I want to show calendar of device through my application. I mean, I want the same look & feel of calendar. Please reply.